# How to increment column regard on another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment

I have following data:

```
(1,'20120615 8:03:43 PM'),
(1,'20120615 8:03:43 PM'),
(1,'20120615 8:03:48 PM'),
(1,'20120615 8:03:53 PM'),
(0,'20120615 8:03:58 PM'),
(1,'20120615 8:04:03 PM'),
(1,'20120615 8:04:08 PM'),
(1,'20120615 8:04:13 PM'),
(1,'20120615 8:04:18 PM'),
(0,'20120615 8:04:23 PM'),
(1,'20120615 8:04:28 PM'),
(1,'20120615 8:04:33 PM');
```

My desired result is:

```
(1,'20120615 8:03:43 PM', 1),
(1,'20120615 8:03:43 PM', 1),
(1,'20120615 8:03:48 PM', 1),
(1,'20120615 8:03:53 PM', 1),
(0,'20120615 8:03:58 PM', 0),
(1,'20120615 8:04:03 PM', 2),
(1,'20120615 8:04:08 PM', 2),
(1,'20120615 8:04:13 PM', 2),
(1,'20120615 8:04:18 PM', 2),
(0,'20120615 8:04:23 PM', 0),
(1,'20120615 8:04:28 PM', 3),
(1,'20120615 8:04:33 PM', 3);
```

In another words I want to group data except 0 like above order.

Comment: well i guess you are not grouping, please help me understand how are you incrementing 1,2,3 or just by seeing 0 if it has zero before the row increment the row? do you have this data in table ?

Comment: Which version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

Comment: Every group have only four rows except the last group ?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the idea.  Create a flag for where each group starts.  This is really `1 - col1` in your data above.  Then take the cumulative sum of this flag.  For values that are not `0`, this is the group.  The following query takes this approach, using correlated subqueries for the computation:

```
select t.col1, t.dt,
       (case when t.col1 = 0 then 0 else 1+grouping end)
from (select t.*,
             (select sum(1-col1)
              from t t2
              where t2.dt <= t.dt
             ) as grouping
      from t
     ) t;
```

In SQL Server 2012, you can do this with a cumulative sum:

```
select t.col1, t.dt,
       (case when col1 = 0 then 0
             else 1+sum(1 - col1) over (order by dt)
        end)
from t;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

**DDL:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Col1 INT, Col2 DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @temp (Col1, Col2)
VALUES 
     (1,'20120615 8:03:43 PM'),
     (1,'20120615 8:03:43 PM'),
     (1,'20120615 8:03:48 PM'),
     (1,'20120615 8:03:53 PM'),
     (0,'20120615 8:03:58 PM'),
     (1,'20120615 8:04:03 PM'),
     (1,'20120615 8:04:08 PM'),
     (1,'20120615 8:04:13 PM'),
     (1,'20120615 8:04:18 PM'),
     (0,'20120615 8:04:23 PM'),
     (1,'20120615 8:04:28 PM'),
     (1,'20120615 8:04:33 PM')
```

**Query:**

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
     SELECT Col2, Col3 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col2)
     FROM @temp t2
     WHERE t2.Col1 = 0
)
SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2, ISNULL(t2.Col3, 0) + t.Col1 
FROM @temp t
OUTER APPLY (
     SELECT TOP 1 Col2, Col3
     FROM cte t2
     WHERE t.Col2 > t2.Col2
          AND t.Col1 = 1
     ORDER BY t2.Col2 DESC
) t2
```

**Output:**

```
Col1        Col2                    Col3
----------- ----------------------- --------------------
1           2012-06-15 20:03:43.000 1
1           2012-06-15 20:03:43.000 1
1           2012-06-15 20:03:48.000 1
1           2012-06-15 20:03:53.000 1
0           2012-06-15 20:03:58.000 0
1           2012-06-15 20:04:03.000 2
1           2012-06-15 20:04:08.000 2
1           2012-06-15 20:04:13.000 2
1           2012-06-15 20:04:18.000 2
0           2012-06-15 20:04:23.000 0
1           2012-06-15 20:04:28.000 3
1           2012-06-15 20:04:33.000 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option with correlated subquery. Instead of MAX function suggested by @Gordon Linoff, this query uses the COUNT function

```
SELECT *, (
           SELECT CASE WHEN t1.IntCol = 0 THEN 0 ELSE COUNT(*) + 1 END
           FROM dbo.test139 t2
           WHERE t2.IntCol = 0
             AND t1.dateCol > t2.dateCol
           ) AS IntCol2
FROM dbo.test139 t1
```

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5627/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, you need to change some column name and table name

```
DECLARE @TABLE_COUNT BIGINT
DECLARE @LOOP_COUNT BIGINT=0
DECLARE @COULMN_A INT
DECLARE @COULMN_B DATETIME
DECLARE @COUNTER BIGINT=1
DECLARE @NEWTABLE TABLE(COULMN_A INT,COLUMN_B DATETIME,COUNTER INT)
SELECT @TABLE_COUNT= COUNT(*) FROM TABLE

WHILE @LOOP_COUNT<@TABLE_COUNT
BEGIN
SELECT @COULMN_A=COLUMN_A,@COULMN_B=COLUMN_B FROM TABLE
IF @COULMN_A=0
SELECT @COUNTER=@COUNTER+1

INSERT INTO @NEWTABLE VALUES(@COULMN_A,@COULMN_B,@COUNTER)

SELECT @LOOP_COUNT=@LOOP_COUNT+1
END

SELECT * FROM @NEWTABLE
```

If need any help in understanding please trouble me

Hope this works

Regards
Ashutosh Arya